# How to determine if an axes already as a colorbar?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I would like to determine if an axes already has a colorbar. I have code which plots many objects on the same axes, but I only want to create and define the colorbar once to make things more efficient. I've tried looking for a `ColorBar` object as a child of the figure handle, but I have multiple subplots in the same figure, and each may or may not need their own colorbar. Is there a way to determine if a particular axes has a colorbar associated with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to [Voss at MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2090686-how-to-determine-if-an-axes-already-has-a-colorbar#answer_1421446)

> There is a hidden axes property called 'Colorbar', which you can use.
>
> ```
> % two axes, one with colorbar, one without
> ax = subplot(2,1,1);
> plot(1:10)
> colorbar()
> ax(2) = subplot(2,1,2);
> plot(1:10)
> ```

```
 ax1_has_colorbar = ~isempty(ax(1).Colorbar)
```

Returns `true`

```
 ax2_has_colorbar = ~isempty(ax(2).Colorbar)
```

Returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `findobj` for that, for example

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1); plot(rand(4));
subplot(2,2,2); imagesc(rand(10)); colorbar
subplot(2,2,3); plot(rand(3)); legend('a','b','c')
subplot(2,2,4); imagesc(rand(32)); colorbar

h = get(gcf,'children');
axes_ind      =  findobj(h,'type','Axes');
legend_ind    =  findobj(h,'type','Legend');
colorbar_ind  =  findobj(h,'type','Colorbar');
```

you can check `h` and also see that colorbar_ind now has access to your colorbars...

note that once you create a colorbar, you create an independent object at some position in the figure, it is not a child of an axes object.

Comment: This is good for finding a colorbar for a given figure, but not for a given axes. For example, if in your code you remove the `colorbar` command from line 5, how do you determine that the first axes has a colorbar but not the second?